# Source map generated is wrong

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-chrome-devtools, metro-bundler, react-native-debugger

I am making an app in React native. I'm using `react-native-debugger` for debugging the app. The debugger is working but the source map generated seems wrong, the logs point to different files. I've tried using the chrome debugger after clearing the cache and it works fine, but when I switch to react-native-debugger the logs are shown incorrectly.

React Native Debugger app version: 0.10.2
React Native version: 0.58.5
Platform: Android
Is it a real device platform: Yes
Operating System: macOS

[image: Logs in chrome debugger]

[image: Logs in react native debugger]